# Adding config file entries to specific sections

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mysql

I am trying to write a script that configures mySQL. Let's say I want to configure the port to 3333, so I want the config file to contain the lines

```
[mysqld]
port=3333
[client]
port=3333
```

At first, I was simply `echo`ing the new lines:

```
echo "[mysqld]" >> /etc/mysql/my.cnf
echo "port=3333" >> /etc/mysql/my.cnf
echo "[client]" >> /etc/mysql/my.cnf
echo "port=3333" >> /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

But then I realized that the config file will contain all entries several times in case I run it multiple times. Therefore I applied a check using a function:

```
function appendconfig {
    grep -qF "$1" "$2" || echo "$1" >> "$2"
}
cfg=/etc/mysql/my.cnf
appendconfig "[client]" $cfg
appendconfig "port=3333" $cfg
appendconfig "[mysqld]" $cfg
appendconfig "port=3333" $cfg
```

That function will only add the line if it does not exist yet.

Unfortunately, when configuring `port=3333` in the `[mysqld]` section, it detects that `port=3333`is already present (but in `[client]`).

What way would I write config files like the one from mySQL in a Linux Bash script?

Basically I'm looking for something like

```
setconfigvalue <section> <value> <file>
```

so I could write

```
setconfigvalue [mysqld] port=3333 /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

---

I have tried the suggestions from [this U&L sister site question "Editing INI like files with a script"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137643/editing-ini-like-files-with-a-script).

The accepted answer just provides solutions which are hard coded for the OP's problem. I would need to adapt them, but that's error prone.

I have tried `crudini`, which seems to be the right tool from its syntax. But it can't parse mySQL config files due to the includes:

```
crudini --get /etc/mysql/my.cnf client port
File contains parsing errors: <???>
    [line 22]: !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
    [line 23]: !includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that I have version 0.7-1 of `crudini` installed from the official packages. There's a newer version [available on Github](https://github.com/pixelb/crudini), 0.9 at the time of writing.

I replaced the old version by the new version using `wget`:

```
wget -q https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pixelb/crudini/master/crud‌​ini -O /usr/bin/crudini
```

That way, the error message about parsing error disappeared:

```
crudini --get /etc/mysql/my.cnf mysqld port
Parameter not found: port
```

And I was able to set the parameters I wanted:

```
crudini --set /etc/mysql/my.cnf mysqld port 3333
crudini --get /etc/mysql/my.cnf mysqld port
3333
```